# Mixed Dirichlet-Neumann Laplacian problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded regular domain (with smooth boundary) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\partial\Omega=\partial\Omega_1 \cup\partial\Omega_2$ be a portion of this domain. Consider the Laplace problem on $\Omega$ with both Dirichlet and Neumann boundary condition
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u =0 &\hbox{in } \Omega\\
u=0 &\hbox{on } \partial\Omega_1\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0 &\hbox{on } \partial\Omega_2
\end{cases}
$$
What can be said about the function? It is identically zero?

Hope someone could help, I don't know where to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this follows from integration by parts. Your boundary conditions imply that

$$0 = \int_\Omega u \Delta u \, dx= -\int_\Omega \vert\nabla u \vert^2 \, dx.$$ Hence, $u$ is constant, but the only constant that is zero on part of the boundary must be 0.